# Regarding String comparision

Tags: java, string

I was checking the string comparison methods used for string compsrsion and explore the string class in the decomplier and come to know that there are  basically four methods

```
equals()
equalsIgnoreCase()
compareTo()
compareToIgnore()
```

Now I want to know the difference between two methods that we use they are equals() and  compareTo() , basically please advise why string class had kept both these methods ..

```
String tv = "Bravia";
        String television = "Bravia";

        // String compare example using equals
        if (tv.equals(television)) {
            System.out.println("Both tv and television contains same letters and equal by equals method of String");
        }

        // String compare example in java using compareTo
        if (tv.compareTo(television) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Both tv and television are equal using compareTo method of String");
        }
```

output :-

```
Both tv and television contains same letters and equal by equals method of String
Both tv and television are equal using compareTo method of String
```

Comment: as you asked. I have implemented it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings implement Comparable interface and then its bound to implement compareTo method.

**Camparable interface**

it facilitates ordering of the object when they are contained in any sorted collection. So when you will put your string in any sorted collection(like TreeSet), how will you tell java how to sort your objects. that's where coompareTo() method comes in seen. it is used by collection to sort your object.

```
String tv = "Bravia";
    String television = "Bravia";

    // String compare example using equals
    if (tv.equals(television)) {
        System.out.println("Both tv and television contains same letters and equal by equals method of String");
    }

    // String compare example in java using compareTo
    if (tv.compareTo(television) == 0) {
        System.out.println("Both tv and television are equal using compareTo method of String");
    }

    if (tv.compareTo(television) < 0){

    System.out.println("tv comes before  using compareTo method of String");
    }

if (tv.compareTo(television) > 0){

    System.out.println("tv comes after using compareTo method of String");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` returns a `boolean`; `true`/`false`. Is string A equal to B?

`compareTo()` returns an integer, representing not only whether the strings are equal, but which one is "lower" than the other - with "lower" defined as the natural alphabetical ordering.

For two strings `a` and `b`, `a.equals(b)` is true if an only if `a.compareTo(b)` is `0`.

For example:

```
String a = "String1";
String b = "String2";
```

`a.compareTo(b)` will return a negative integer (not necessarily `-1`!), because, alphabetically, the string "String1" is lower than "String2"; if you were to sort the two strings in ascending order, "String1" would come first. Also, `a.equals(b)` will return `false`, because the strings are not equal.

However:

```
String a = "Example";
String b = "Example";
```

In this case, `a.compareTo(b)` will return `0` (because the strings are equal), and `a.equals(b)` will return `true` (again, because the strings are equal).

With respect to the "ignoreCase" variants:

```
String a = "String1";
String b = "string1";
```

In this case, `a.compareToIgnoreCase(b)` will return `0`; that's because, when case is ignored, the two strings are identical. Also, `a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)` will return `0`, for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for compareTo() can you please explain with an example, so that I can understand completely

Answer (score 1):

`equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase` return a `boolean` value that say "one is either equal to another, or is not"

`compareTo` and `compareToIgnoreCase()` return a tristate integer, `0`, `-1` or `1`

- `0` if they're equal comparing each ordinally
- `1` if the 
  argument to `compareTo*()` is greater in ordinal than the object you invoke `compareTo*()` on
- `-1` if the argument to `compareTo*()` is lesser in
  ordinal than the object you invoke `compareTo*()` on.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are needed. String inherits equals from Object, and compareTo is required when implementing the Comparable interface.

Answer (score 0):

`compareTo()`: return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object. from [compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)

`equals()`: The equals() method compares two objects for equality and returns true if they are equals else return false source [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html)